# running SPEC in gem5 using the SimPoint methodology

Tags: performance, cpu-architecture, simulator, gem5

I'm currently doing a project using gem5 to simulate some different system configurations to test the difference in their performance. I would like to run SPEC2017/2006 for benchmarking the performance. My professor advised us to use the simpoint methodology for performing these simulations, and thus that is what we're doing. There are some issues we have run into and there does not seem to be much official documentation/past information on online forums that has been of help to us, and so I'm making this post to see if anyone recognize any of these problems.

We have generated the SimPoints (instruction number & weights) as well as BBV through valgrind, and are trying to establish checkpoints in gem5, unfortunately the example scripts(se.py, fs.py) used in the [official tutorial](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/checkpoints/) have since been deprecated and there seems to be a lack of otherwise clear documentation for the entire process. for example it is unclear how to calculated an appropriate interval before a checkpoint for cache-warm.

Additionally, we have some confusion on how to actually set SPEC as a workload for gem5 to run, we have tried on different environments (wsl Ubuntu, docker) to follow the [official tutorial](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/gem5art/tutorials/spec-tutorial) that encountered, at different points, different rather obscure roadblocks that seems undocumented and thus has halted our progress.

Finally I want to say that most of this stuff is rather new to me so any inconsistencies or inaccuracies in the above sections please understand. Any relevant solutions or other information is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend reaching out on the gem5 Slack server as you'll get advice from a more specific group of experts. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I did try looking for a slack but all the links I've found is unfortunately expired :(